# How to display symbols in stack trace of google-perftools heap profiler

Tags: google-perftools, pprof, heap-profiling

We're using google-perftools heap profiler in a TDD environment. We get the heap dump at the end that we can use pprof to see the hot spots. It shows the symbols but gives little to no information about how the leak is reached in the stack. In fact, there's no organization in the output that I can see whatsoever.

The stack trace of the largest leak is displayed at runtime but does not show any symbols. We're correctly setting the PPROF_PATH environment variable but it's not having any effect. How can we enable this?

Comment: You seem to be having two separate problems, which confuses me.

You initially say that you are getting symbols but "no organization". The results should be arranged by call stacks in a fairly intuitive format. If you aren't getting call stacks then maybe libunwind is misbehaving, or maybe you are building without stack frames.

You then say that you are getting a stack trace but no symbols, which seems to contradict the first paragraph.

I find google perftools to be finicky (it can fail without warning or with cryptic errors) but it is working for me.